# How can I solve the ODE $f''(t) + \frac{f'(t)}{t} = 0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to solve the following ODE
\begin{align}
f^{''}(t) + \frac{1}{t} f^{'}(t) &= 0 \\
f(1)&=0
\end{align}
Is this an Euler-type ODE?

In order to find the solution, i have to rearrange the ODE, as
\begin{equation}
t f^{''}(t) + f^{'}(t)=0
\end{equation}
Then the solution is of the form $f(t)=t^{\alpha}$. Then substitute this solution back and find the value of $\alpha$? Is my thinking right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\textbf{hint}$

$$
f''+\frac{1}{t}f' = \dfrac{tf'' +f'}{t} =\dfrac{1}{t}\dfrac{d}{dt}\left( tf' \right) = 0
$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: I think, i will integrate based on my boundary condition. Thank you very much.

Comment: If i set $g=f^{'}$ i arrive at $g^{'} + \frac{1}{t}g=0$, which is a simple first order ode. Then, i find the solution $g$ and afterwards, by integrating, i also find the original solution $f$. Do you agree?

Comment: Pretty much. You get two constants of integration. find one by the condition then the second by placing in the original ode.